# ArangoDB connection fail: Reached the end of the stream

Tags: kubernetes, arangodb, micronaut

i am struggle with the first setup of a simple arangodb server
therefore i use that config from the tutorial

```
apiVersion: "database.arangodb.com/v1alpha"
kind: "ArangoDeployment"
metadata:
  name: "arangodb"
spec:
  mode: Single
```

On client side i use `com.github.goodforgod:micronaut-arangodb` which bundles the `arangodb-java-driver` and integrates it into micronaut.

The connection settings are also pretty straight forward (`application.yaml`)

```
arangodb:
  hosts:
    - arangodb.default.svc:8529
  database: mydb
  user: myuser
  password: mypw
```

From the logs on client side i get that

```
2021-09-21 17:35:34,593 [scheduled-executor-thread-2] DEBUG com.arangodb.internal.ArangoDBImpl - ArangoDB Client is ready to use
2021-09-21 17:35:34,628 [scheduled-executor-thread-2] DEBUG c.a.i.v.internal.VstConnection - [connection_1632245734627_0.2727626330130274]: Connection created
2021-09-21 17:35:34,628 [scheduled-executor-thread-2] DEBUG c.a.internal.net.ConnectionPoolImpl - Return Connection connection_1632245734627_0.2727626330130274
2021-09-21 17:35:34,630 [scheduled-executor-thread-2] DEBUG c.a.i.v.internal.VstConnection - [connection_1632245734627_0.2727626330130274]: Open connection to host[addr=arangodb.default.svc,port=8529]
2021-09-21 17:35:34,689 [scheduled-executor-thread-2] DEBUG c.a.i.v.internal.VstConnection - [connection_1632245734627_0.2727626330130274]: Connected to Socket[addr=arangodb.default.svc/10.0.5.236,port=8529,localport=44532]
2021-09-21 17:35:34,694 [scheduled-executor-thread-2] DEBUG c.a.i.v.internal.VstConnection - [connection_1632245734627_0.2727626330130274]: Send velocystream protocol header to Socket[addr=arangodb.default.svc/10.0.5.236,port=8529,localport=44532]
2021-09-21 17:35:34,703 [scheduled-executor-thread-2] DEBUG c.a.i.v.VstCommunicationSync - Send Message (id=1, head=[1,1000,"plain","myuser","mypw"], body={})
2021-09-21 17:35:34,708 [scheduled-executor-thread-2] DEBUG c.a.i.v.internal.VstConnection - [connection_1632245734627_0.2727626330130274]: Send chunk 1:1 from message 1
2021-09-21 17:35:34,712 [pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG c.a.i.v.internal.VstConnection - [connection_1632245734627_0.2727626330130274]: Start Callable
2021-09-21 17:35:34,714 [pool-3-thread-1] ERROR c.a.i.v.internal.MessageStore - Reached the end of the stream.
java.io.IOException: Reached the end of the stream.
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.internal.VstConnection.readBytesIntoBuffer(VstConnection.java:348)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.internal.VstConnection.readBytes(VstConnection.java:340)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.internal.VstConnection.readChunk(VstConnection.java:315)
    at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.internal.VstConnection.lambda$open$0(VstConnection.java:212)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
2021-09-21 17:35:34,716 [pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG c.a.i.v.internal.MessageStore - Exceptionally complete Message (id=1).
2021-09-21 17:35:34,717 [scheduled-executor-thread-2] DEBUG c.a.i.v.internal.VstConnection - [connection_1632245734627_0.2727626330130274]: Close connection Socket[addr=arangodb.default.svc/10.0.5.236,port=8529,localport=44532]
2021-09-21 17:35:34,728 [pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG c.a.i.v.internal.VstConnection - [connection_1632245734627_0.2727626330130274]: Stop Callable
```

So it seems to me that he is able to open up a socket connection but fails afterwards for reading data. The server logs contains nothing.

So i am quite lost how to proceed with that issue?
Any help is welcome
Regards
Oliver

Comment: You are rght, the socket should be open and then closed from the other end (loadbalancer). I guess it could be something related to ssl configuration. 

Also you can try using http communication protocol and see if you get a more informative error message.

Comment: @rashtao thx for the answer. i also had that in mind, cause the certificate is self signed and therefore maybe blocked. how to use the http communication protocol? i tried already that one: https://github.com/arangodb/kube-arangodb/blob/master/examples/single-server-no-auth.yaml but than i have the issue of an public endpoint without user authentication which is even for dev no option.

Comment: The driver config should be sth like:

`        ArangoDB arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder()
                .useProtocol(Protocol.HTTP_JSON)
                .host("...", 8529)
                .useSsl(true)
                .sslContext(...)
                .password("...")
                .build();
`

Comment: I was able to make it working by switching back to http but in that case the load balancer is exposing a http endpoint which is a realy bad idea. so it realy seems that the self signed certs are causing the problem. Thx for your settings, i will give them also a try. Otherwise i am thinking about eighter hiding the public ip of the loadbalancer and put him behind my default ingress controller, who provides tls with letsencrypt certificates.